# How to write 2 files for one controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

There is example of my `controller` that I want to split to 2 files.

**Monitor.js**

```
var feederliteModule = angular.module('FeederLiteApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

feederliteModule.controller('WiFiMonitor', function(
ajax_post,
delay,
switcher,
maps,
$scope,
$http,
$timeout,
$q,
$filter)
 {

 $scope.method_1 = function(){
    /*....*/
 }

 $scope.method_2 = function(){
    /*....*/
 }    


});

feederliteModule.$inject = [
    'ajax_post',
    'delay',
    'switcher',
    'maps',
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$timeout',
    '$q',
    '$filter'
];
```

The content of my controller is big and I have parts of code that I don't mange to change.

**How can I extract part of controller code to different file?**

In my case I want put `$scope.method_2` method in other file but still be able to call

`$scope.method_2` from `$scope.method_1` and all global parameters should be visible in both files.

Thank you,

Comment: I believe you could just define the functions in the global scope then refer to them in your actual angular controller, but I think this is just a bad practice.  It would be nice if there were some way to do the equivalent of a C# partial class but I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part1.js:

```
var buildPart1 = function(ajax_post, ..., $scope, ...) {
    $scope.foo = ...;
    $scope.bar = ...;
};
```

Part2.js:

```
var buildPart2 = function(ajax_post, ..., $scope, ...) {
    $scope.qix = ...;
    $scope.baz = ...;
};
```

Monitor.js:

```
feederliteModule.controller('WiFiMonitor', function(ajax_post, ..., $scope, ...) {
    buildPart1(ajax_post, ..., $scope, ...);
    buildPart2(ajax_post, ..., $scope, ...);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response, what about if `feederliteModule.controller` in Monitor.js has variable `$scope.myvar = 0;` Should it be visible in  `Part1.js` and `Part2.js`?

Comment: It's part of the $scope object, and this $scope object is passed to buildPart1() and buildPart2(), so yes, it will be visible.